# Change Call Screen

Tags: android, screen, customization, phone-call, dtmf

I need to change or customize the call screen when initiating a call on Android.

After searching on google I do not find any way to do it.

There is no way to send DTMF tones during a call, the idea is to send a specific number to the call screen. So when a call is made is possible to see the number to dial during a call to the PBX.

I tried to putting the number in the "status bar", but the notification hide after seconds and it is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible to show a toast message or a dialog in front of the call screen from a background process I think.

This won't look nice but would be a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I already have tried to put a toast message but it disappears in seconds.

How do I show a message to stay on top of call screen without it disappears?

Answer (score 1):

> I need to change or customize the call
>   screen when initiating a call on
>   Android.

This is not possible, the call screen can not be customised or changed unless you are building your own ROM.

> There is no way to send DTMF tones
>   during a call

You can add a dtmf sequence to the end of a dial intent to send dtmf straight after a call has connected but not during a call.

> I appreciate any other suggestion.

You could try to overlay the number in some way but I'm not quite sure what you actually want to achieve so that suggestion may be incorrect

Comment: Intent mIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneNumber + ";" + dtmfSequence));

Comment: Thanks Rafferty ;) I'll try...

But how can I encode the # sign on dtmfsequence???

Comment: yes, example:
tel:<phonenumber>;<password#extension>

The pbx always asks for the password.